# SQL Server Partition. How would splitting range with Guid work?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, uuid

I have a very large table in my database, and it has a GUID column called Group_Id.  This Group_Id has a pretty even split of data, and it would be beneficial to partition the table by this column.

I've created the partition function and scheme, and whenever a new Group is added to the table, I split the Range on the new Group_Id.  Normally, this operation goes quickly.  However, I've noticed that while the table is in use (I do jobs that do a lot of reads/writes at once), the partition split takes a LONG time.  How can I make the SPLIT RANGE operation go faster?

I know conventional wisdom says that I should be incrementing ints, and splitting right on the new int Id.  Would this solve my problem?

What is really happening when I do the split? I thought since all the Guids live on a border in the partition, it wouldn't have to move any data, it would just have to insert the new range?n